# Flow Traders' arithmetic test

Tags: career

I am preparing for the [Flow Traders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_Traders) test. What are the beste sources for this? I've used Zetamac's [Arithmetic Game](https://arithmetic.zetamac.com) before, but I am curious if there is anything better available as well.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Both seem like great platforms, I'll try it out

Comment: Just out of curiosity, whats a reasonable score for the arithmetic game? what should one aim at?

Comment: You need to score 72 points (60%) to pass the test, so I personally aimed for around 80 points consistently during practice to account for stress and such during the real test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used https://www.tradinginterview.com/ they have a test for Flow Traders and Optiver and some additional material to prepare.

Answer (score 7):

There is https://www.tradermath.org/, which I believe is closest to what you are looking for as it offers tests for Flow Traders specifically as well as for Optiver and Akuna Capital.

[image]

Comment: Used this one as well their test is very representative for flow.

Comment: This one is the most representative in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

There is also https://tradermaths.com/ its free and you can also practice with friends using Duo mode.